# How do I create dynamic number of elements in React outside of JSX?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, electron-react

In a electron-react app I run a shell command and the output is received line by line, how do I create elements dynamically and add it to DOM?

I use this method which works but, is there a better way to do this?

```js
import Titlebar from "./components/Titlebar/Titlebar"
import { useState } from "react"

let shellOutput = []
const [currentShellOutput, setCurrentShellOutput] = useState(shellOutput)
ElectronAPI.execShellCommands(["spicetify apply"])
ElectronAPI.receive("sendToRenderer/shell-output", (outputString) => {
    console.log(outputString)
    setCurrentShellOutput((value) => {
        return value.concat([outputString])
    })
})

export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Titlebar></Titlebar>
            {currentShellOutput.map((output) => (
                <p className="terminal-output">{output}</p>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

output on left and right are same I didn't format that, so don't care about them
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `spicetify` shell prints `shell-exited` when it finishes the work. So why don't you create an array that you fill with data in the background and render to the DOM only once the shell is exited?

```js
const shellOutput = [];
ElectronAPI.execShellCommands(["spicetify apply"])
ElectronAPI.receive("sendToRenderer/shell-output", (outputString) => {
    if (outputString === 'shell-exited') {
        // update the state
        setCurrentShellOutput(shellOutput)
        return; // a return statement will exit the function
    }
    console.log(outputString)
    shellOutput.push(outputString);
})
```

Comment: i want the output to be live because not all the lines print at the same time. some lines takes more time to print so user can know the process is running

Comment: In that case, I don't see any better way to implement this. Also, is it by a purpose that the `useState` and shell execution are outside the `App` component?

Comment: No it can be inside jsx, i wrote it like that so it looks clean. so is there a better method if we execute them inside `App` component? if yes then how its done

Comment: Usually, React hooks are used only inside components, which isn't the case here, at least not from the code snippet you've attached. I don't well-know electron to say it is fine, but I guess if React didn't warn you about it, it is fine. The way I would do it is to create a useEffect inside the component and perform the shell execution there).